# <ng-template> show in other component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I have 2 components.

The `.html` of parent component this is the code:

```
<div class="space">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{item: item}">
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</div>

    <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item="item">
        <div class="host">
            <img class='card-img-top'
                src={{item.image}}
                >
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <h6 class="title">{{item.projectTitle}}</h6>
            <hr>

            <ng-container *ngIf="item.type=='inactive'">
                <button id="inactive"
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-warning py-0 custom-button text-uppercase">{{item.type}}</button>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

All code since line: `<ng-template #itemTemplate let-item="item">`

It's necessary to show in the `.html` of the child component.

This is the .`ts` of parent component

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, OnInit, TemplateRef, Input, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';
import listProjects from './projects.json';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-view',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss'],
})
export class ParentComponent {
  public items: any = listProjects;
  @ContentChild('itemTemplate', { read: TemplateRef }) itemTemplate: ViewContainerRef;
```

How can show the `<ng-template #itemTemplate let-item="item">` in other component?

Comment: Can the child just render `ng-content`?

Comment: Sorry Now, I complete the code. I use [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplate"

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just put that html in the template of your child component?

Comment: Yes, It's necessary to have a generic component such header of other components

Comment: Then why wouldn't you have a child component which is `header-component` and you use that everywhere you need it. You could simply put `Input()` with variables that you might need to pass into it.

Comment: it's necessary to pass item for item. I cannot send all the list(object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem:

File: `projects-tile-view-components.ts`

```
export class ProjectsTileViewComponent {
  @ViewChild('tileViewItems', { static: true }) tileViewItemTemplate: TileViewComponent;
  public items = listProjects;
  public type = 'etb';
  constructor() {}

  addItems(e) {
    if (this.type === 'osd') {
      this.type = 'etb';
    } else {
      this.type = 'osd';
    }
  }
}
```

the file `projects-tile-view-components.html`

```
<lib-tile-view [items]="items" #tileViewItems>
    <ng-template #tileViewItem let-item>
        <div [ngSwitch]="type">
            <lib-osd-tile-view-item [item]="item" *ngSwitchCase="'osd'"></lib-osd-tile-view-item>
            <lib-osd-tile-view-item [item]="item" *ngSwitchDefault></lib-osd-tile-view-item>
            <lib-etb-tile-view-item [item]="item" *ngSwitchCase="'etb'"></lib-etb-tile-view-item>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</lib-tile-view>
```

the file `view-item.ts` (interface)

```
export interface ViewItem {
  item: any;
}
```

the file `tile-view-components.html`

```
<div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tileViewItemTemplate; context: {$implicit: item}">
        </ng-container> 
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

the file `tile-view-item.components.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-tile-view',
  templateUrl: './tile-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tile-view.component.scss'],
})
export class TileViewComponent {
  @Input()
  public items: any;
  @ContentChild('tileViewItem', { static: true }) tileViewItemTemplate;
}
```

the file `osd-tile-view-components.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-osd-tile-view-item',
  templateUrl: './osd-tile-view-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./osd-tile-view-item.component.scss'],
})
export class OsdTileViewItemComponent implements ViewItem {
  @Input() item: any;
  public projectView() {
    alert('show project');
  }
}
```

the file `osd-tile-view-item.components.html`

```
<div class="host" fxFlex="0 1 calc(100% - 32px)" fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(100% - 32px)" fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" (click) = 'projectView()'>
    <img class='img-fluid img-thumbnail' src={{item?.image}} alt='logo nih'>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <h6 class="title">{{item?.projectTitle}}</h6>
    <p class="small"><span class="text-muted small text-uppercase">ZIA ID
            Number:</span>{{item?.number}}</p>

</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it possible the full example because I do the same thing and it does not work

Answer (score -1):

You need to share this `TemplateRef` in service (if you want to have access in every component in your application), and then in other component you can read this reference and do something with it - because if you want to pass this reference only to child, then you can use `@Input()` in child component, but if it should be available across all components, then you need to create service.

service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TemplateService {
  someTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

componentA:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-view',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss'],
})
export class ParentComponent {
  public items: any = listProjects;
  @ViewChild('itemTemplate', { read: TemplateRef }) set itemTemplate(value) {
    this.ts.someTemplate = value;
  }
  construtor(private ts: TemplateService) {}
}
```

then in any other component, you can read this template reference

componentB:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'component-b',
  templateUrl: './component-b.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-b.component.scss'],
})
export class ComponentBComponent {
  get itemTemplateReference() {
    return this.ts.itemTemplate;
  }
  construtor(private ts: TemplateService) {}
}
```

`.html` of componentB

```html
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplateReference"></ng-container>
```

And it should render the same `<ng-template>`

Comment: I don't understand. No is it possible to use the ng-template?

Comment: I added more info into my answer